# How to validate if data and column headers in the table are refreshed or not

Tags: java, selenium

Given : There is table with 3 rows and 5 columns and a refresh button . After Refresh button is triggered, the data along with the column headers (3 columns headers) getting changed on every refresh except 2 columns headers.

How can we handle such a scenario using selenium?

Thanks

Comment: Normally Data is changed and not the attributes/locators of table elements.Can you share the HTML code of it so that i can review an provide the selenium code.Without seeing that we can't able to say as modern controls are not using <table><tr><td> tags instead using ul and li tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your table is defined as a normal [HTML `<table>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
        <th>Header 4</th>
        <th>Header 5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 1 cell 1</td>
        <td>row 1 cell 2</td>
        <td>row 1 cell 3</td>
        <td>row 1 cell 4</td>
        <td>row 1 cell 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 2 cell 1</td>
        <td>row 2 cell 2</td>
        <td>row 2 cell 3</td>
        <td>row 2 cell 4</td>
        <td>row 2 cell 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 3 cell 1</td>
        <td>row 3 cell 2</td>
        <td>row 3 cell 3</td>
        <td>row 3 cell 4</td>
        <td>row 3 cell 5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can access header cell values via [`<th>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_th.asp) and normal cell values via [`<td>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_td.asp).

Therefore you can select "interesting" cells via [XPath expressions](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp), for example:

- all header cell values except `Header 4` and `Header 5`:

  ```
  //table/descendant::*/th[not(text()='Header 4') and not(text()='Header 5')]
  ```
- all other cell values:

  ```
  //table/descendant::*/td
  ```
- 2 expressions results can be combined using [union `|` XPath Operator](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

---

Assuming all above you need to:

1. Collect 3 header cells and 15 normal cells values into a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of [Strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

   ```
   List<String> cellsBeforeRefresh = driver
           .findElements(By
                   .xpath("//table/descendant::*/th[not(text()='Header 4') and not(text()='Header 5')] " +
                           "| //table/descendant::*/td"))
           .stream()
           .map(WebElement::getText)
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```

   [image]
2. Do what you need to refresh the page
3. Repeat step 1 but store the result into another List of Strings

   ```
   List<String> cellsAfterRefresh = driver
           .findElements(By
                   .xpath("//table/descendant::*/th[not(text()='Header 4') and not(text()='Header 5')]" +
                           " | //table/descendant::*/td"))
           .stream()
           .map(WebElement::getText)
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```
4. And finally compare 2 lists using [List.equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) function

   ```
   if (cellsBeforeRefresh.equals(cellsAfterRefresh)) {
       // tables are the same
   } else {
       //tables differ
   }
   ```

Also be aware that [Yandex HtmlElements library](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/htmlelements) provides handy [Table](http://javadox.com/ru.yandex.qatools.htmlelements/htmlelements-java/1.10/ru/yandex/qatools/htmlelements/element/Table.html) class which can make your life easier when it comes to working with HTML Tables.